# I need to perform subtraction and a filter in the same column that I create in Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD3Hh.png)

I need to  create a column which subtracts [Retailer_yes_amount] and [classification_base_amount] and at the same time filter out "Not Eligible" category in [Classification] column. [Classification] column has 5 categories - Platinum, Gold, Silver, Bronze and Not eligible.

I was thinking like this New_column = calculate(([Retailer_yes_amount]-[classification_base_amount]),filter('table_name',[classification] <> "Not Eligible")) but it threw an error.

Kindly suggest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have this evaluated for every row as a new column you have to enter the following expression as a **Calculated Column**

```
New_column = 
IF( 
    table_name[Classification] <> "Not Eligible", 
    [Retailer_yes_amount] - [classification_base_amount]
)
```

If you want to use a measure you have to specify an aggregation.

Comment: Thank you peter. Works exactly like I need it. kudos!!